# How to use operators on the LAG function column

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, lag

I want to find the temperature that was > 10 from the difference between temperatures of today and the previous day column.
I was able to use LAG function on temperaturehigh column to calculate the difference temperaturehigh today and previous day. However, from the difference column, I don't know how to find the temperature that was > 10.

I tried to use the below SQL code but was not successful. Please assist.

```
select date, temperaturehigh,
temperaturehigh - LAG(temperaturehigh) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS 
difference_previous_day
from regiontemp
where region = 'United Kingdom'
and temperaturehigh - LAG(temperaturehigh) > 10
order by date desc
```

Please, find part of my data below.

[the daily temperature dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7YNV.png)

Comment: That's SQL, not Python. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql, but I want to know how to find the temperature > 10 from the difference between temperaturehigh today and previous day column.